# Does Groovy syntax authorizes multiline lists/arrays?

Tags: arrays, list, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I can't find any documentation about multiline lists or arrays in Groovy.
Many articles exist about comments or strings, but I got no luck regarding lists...

Given this example code :

```
def something = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Will it still work rewritten this way :

```
def something = [
  "a", 
  "b", 
  "c"
]
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: yes.  Did you try?  Or was it quicker to ask here?

Comment: I could'nt try it yet, thanks a lot

Comment: np there's a repl over here you can use online to try things like this out: https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/

Comment: did you find any info FORBIDDING it? saying that usual java conventions are about comma-separated multilines do not apply?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, multiline lists/arrays are perfectly valid, e.g. all of the following are allowed

```
def list = [
  "a", 
  "b", 
  "c"
]

List<String> anotherList = [
  "a", 
  "b", 
  "c"
]

String[] array = [
  "a", 
  "b", 
  "c"
]
```

The equivalent Java syntax for creating an array can also span multiple lines, though you do need to terminate the statement with a semicolon, e.g.

```
String[] array = new String[] {
  "a", 
  "b", 
  "c"
};
```